# StatusBar text color doesn't changed

Tags: android, android-statusbar

I am changing status bar background color with this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(getColorByResourceId(this, android.R.color.white));
        }
    }

    @ColorInt
    public int getColorByResourceId(@NonNull Context context, @ColorRes int resourceId) {
        return ResourcesCompat.getColor(context.getResources(), resourceId, null);
    }

}
```

Background changed well, but text color doesn't changed (it white too):

[image: status bar]

I am using Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar. How to make status bar text color dark?

Answer (score 2):

You can not set a specific `textColor` to the `statusBar`. But you can make it visible on your `statusBar` background for API >= 23

As your statusBar is **White**, you can add the below attribute in your **Base Application Theme** or your custom statusBar theme:

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

It will make texts slightly grayish which will make them visible on your white background.

Comment: But as I know, status bar text color should change automatically related to background color. In my case that is not occurring. It looks like some system bug.

Comment: Yeah, it should change on colorPrimaryDark. Unfortunately it didn't work for me.